# gcc linking error, " Declaration of typedef struct changes meaning of typedef struct"

Tags: c

I actually have a bigger code base but i am sharing the simple code snippet to simplify the problem.

header.h =>

```
typedef struct
{
int foo;
} mystruct;

typedef struct
{
mystruct mystruct;
} struct2;
```

While linking gcc throws error that, ' error : declaration of mystruct ::mystruct'

" error : changes meaning of 'mystruct' from typedef struct mystruct mystruct

I am unable to remove the typedefs because there are too many of them, and i have to use this header file in my code. Is there any workaround to resolve this error?? I have tried one method to use :: operator
like,

```
typedef struct
{
::mystruct mystruct;
} struct2;
```

but this creates another error "error : expected specifier-qualifier-list before ':' token
::mystruct "
^

Is there any way to resolve these errors but to keep the header file and type definitions same??

Comment: `::mystruct mystruct;` is not C syntax. It's C++ syntax.

Comment: As for your problem, `mystruct mystruct;`? That's like declaring a variable like `int int;`. You can't have a type-name as a variable-name (or function-name, or any other name).

Comment: in windows it compiles but while i am migrating to linux, i am seeing this error

Comment: Assuming you use MSVC on Windows, it's really a C++ compiler and not a C compiler, C is an extension for it, so it sometimes allow some things that are valid C++ but that are invalid C. And it doesn't allow things that are valid C. Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, together with a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the build-log, including the commands you use to build.

Comment: Also a little nitpicking, you're not getting a link error, it's a proper compiler error because you use invalid C code.